# How to create custom annotations like BeanProperty

Tags: scala, annotations

In Scala it's possible to use the annotation @BeanProperty to automatically generate getters and setters to a field.

How can I create my own annotation that behaves like that?

I'm interested in creating annotations that changes the source code, like @BeanProperty does.

As an example, how could I create an annotation that only generated get methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two words: [compiler plugin](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140). It is not easy, and the documentation is sparse, but that is one way to do it.

Future versions of Scala will likely have [macro support](http://scalamacros.org/), which gives you much of the same flexability.

Comment: I thought the annotation was something easier to integrate, but there was no source on the BeanProperty class. I'll wait for the macro support, which will likely behave more seamlessly than compiler plugins (which I cannot use due some restrictions). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ViniciusSeufitele - yeah, `BeanProperty` is just an annotation; it's the compiler that does the work of generating the extra methods.