# Is it possible to implement something akin to Scala's @BeanProperty with macros?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I would like to create an annotation or trait that adds methods to an object at compile time dynamically, based on existing fields. Although I'm interested in something at the class-level, I'd also work with field-level annotations (or something else more granular) as well.

[An older stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057119/how-to-create-custom-annotations-like-beanproperty) asking about the implementation details of Scala's `@BeanProperty` was answered with, "It's a compiler plugin, but macros may also allow you to do this". Given the official (if experimental) release of macros in Scala 2.10, is this sort of functionality now possible?

Comment: As far as I understand, it isn't, but should be in a future version, probably 2.11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** This answer is not valid anymore. See Eugenes comment.

No, it is not yet possible.

In 2.10 there exists only def macros that can't do anything comparable. For 2.11 the world is a bit better, [macro annotations](https://github.com/scalamacros/kepler/commit/35420ab3149074b18ffeda58d5ae45eb8ffadb9e) and an implementation to [introduce members](https://github.com/scalamacros/kepler/commit/fd2374d013f1f5cd0b3b0ba6ac16b437d116651b) to classes already exists. But they are only some weeks old and therefore will work only for some corner cases. Furthermore the implementation to introduce members to classes lives in a different branch than the implementation for macro annotations, thus it is not yet possible to use them together.

Comment: Already possible with the recent macro paradise 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT release: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html. Paradise is now a plugin for 2.10, so it can be used right away. More information here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/scala-user/VBHrGB3nw9Y

Comment: @EugeneBurmako: Yes, this is how things change. ;) I updated the answer with the new information.

Comment: A tutorial showing how implementing @BeanProperty using macros would be nice ;)